# How to ignore an unknown column when loading to bigQuery using Airflow?

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I'm loading data from Google Storage to bigQuery using `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator`

It may be that the Json file will have more columns than what I defined. In that case I want the load job continue - simply ignore this unrecognized column.
I tried to use the `ignore_unknown_values` argument but it didn't make any difference.

My operator:

```
def dc():
    return [
    {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "storeId",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
 ...
]
gcs_to_bigquery_st = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='load_to_BigQuery_stage',
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
    destination_project_dataset_table=table_name_template_st,
    source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    source_objects=[gcs_export_uri_template],
    ignore_unknown_values = True,
    schema_fields=dc(),
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
    skip_leading_rows = 1,
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
    bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID
)
```

The error:

> u'Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row
>   starting at position 0: No such field: shippingService.',

which is true. shippingService doesn't exist and it won't be added to the table.

How can I fix this?

Edit:
Removed the `schema_fields=dc()` from the operator:

```
gcs_to_bigquery_st = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='load_to_BigQuery_stage',
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
    destination_project_dataset_table=table_name_template_st,
    source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    source_objects=[gcs_export_uri_template],
    ignore_unknown_values = True,
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
    skip_leading_rows = 1,
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
    bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID
)
```

Still gives the same error.
This doesn't make scene.. It has command to ignore unknown values :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is you are probably using Airflow 1.9. This feature was added in **Airflow 1.10**.

However, you can use it as follows in **Airflow 1.9** by adding `src_fmt_configs={'ignoreUnknownValues': True}`:

```
gcs_to_bigquery_st = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='load_to_BigQuery_stage',
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
    destination_project_dataset_table=table_name_template_st,
    source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    source_objects=[gcs_export_uri_template],
    src_fmt_configs={'ignoreUnknownValues': True},
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
    skip_leading_rows = 1,
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
    bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID
)
```

Comment: Thx! the lack of ability to move between versions of docs is really a problem!

Comment: I recommend to use `ReadTheDocs` https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.9.0/
https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/